# MySQL concat column's results are merged when a having command is used

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, having

Say I have the following query where I merge multiple columns into a column and check their values and convert them to a date time format for a column named `next_execute`:

```
    select
        DISTINCT queues_job.queue_id,
        queues.id,
        MAX(queues_job.created_at) as last_executed,
        CONCAT(
            IF( queues.year = "*", CAST( DATE_FORMAT( NOW(),"%Y" ) as char ), queues.year ),
            "-",
            IF( queues.month_of_the_year = "*", CAST( DATE_FORMAT( NOW(),"%m" ) as char ), queues.month_of_the_year ),
            "-",
            IF( queues.day_of_the_month = "*", CAST( DATE_FORMAT( NOW(),"%d" ) as char ), queues.day_of_the_month ),
            " ",
            IF( queues.hour = "*", CAST( DATE_FORMAT( NOW(),"%H" ) as char ), queues.hour ),
            ":",
            IF( queues.minute = "*", CAST( DATE_FORMAT( NOW(),"%m" ) as char ), queues.minute ),
            ":",
            "00"
        ) as next_execute
    from `queues`
    LEFT JOIN `queues_job` ON `queues_job`.`queue_id` = `queues`.`id`

    GROUP BY queues_job.queue_id, queues.id

    HAVING last_executed < next_execute

    ORDER BY last_executed DESC
```

expected output:

```
queue_id,id,last_executed,next_execute
3,"3","2019-03-13 10:55:05","2019-03-13 12:00:00"
1,"1","2019-03-13 10:55:05","2019-03-13 12:30:00"
2,"2","2019-03-13 10:55:05","2019-03-13 12:15:00"
```

actual output

```
queue_id,id,last_executed,next_execute
3,"3","2019-03-13 10:02:51","2019-03-13 12:30:00-03-13 12:15:00-03-13
1,"1","2019-03-13 10:55:05","2019-03-13 12:30:00"
2,"2","2019-03-13 10:16:07","2019-03-13 12:30:00-03-13 12:15:00"
```

12:00:00"

It appears the `CONCAT` command keeps merging every row into it's own column, which disables it's use for comparing the `last_executed` and `next_execute` values.

Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: Does it work if you add all the columns used inside select statement to the group by?

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: @Strawberry I have revised my question based on your comment.

Comment: @SalmanA column next_execute can be added to the GROUP BY, but last_executed cannot with message "#1056 - Can't group on 'last_executed'". Adding next_execute to the GROUP BY has no effect however.